# Elixir - Points bot using Ecto

Tags: elixir

I'm making a bot that will be used for "points" tracking and such, like a reward system and I'm using Ecto with `postgrex`, this is my approach so far, it works but I'm not sure if I'm doing it in an "Elixir", functional way or if I can improve this a bit ^-^

```
defmodule Cord.Commands do
  ...
  def add_me(msg) do 
    case Repo.get_by(Rewards, user: msg.author.id) do
      # Adds user if it doesn't exist
      nil ->
        case Repo.insert(%Rewards{user: msg.author.id}) do
          {:ok, _struct} ->
            Api.create_message(msg.channel_id, ":white_check_mark:")
          {:error, _changeset} ->
            Api.create_message(msg.channel_id, ":x:")
        end
      _ ->
        Api.create_message(msg.channel_id, "You're already registered")
    end
  end

  # Maps to each id in the list and updates each one
  def thanks(msg) do
    Enum.map msg.mentions, fn user ->
      repo_user = Repo.get_by(Rewards, user: user.id)
      points = repo_user.quantity
      repo_user = Ecto.Changeset.change(repo_user, quantity: points + 1)
      Repo.update!(repo_user)
      Api.create_message(msg.channel_id, "#{msg.author.username} gave a :cookie: to #{user.username}")
    end    
  end

  def not_found(_), do: IO.inspect :ignore
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few suggestions...

You could DRY up your code in `add_me` by returning the string and then making the API call in one place. Also, you should call Repo.insert/1 with a changeset. This will ensure your validation is checked. You can also remove the nesting with the `with` special form. Its a really handy function that I recommend you learn if haven't already.

```
  def add_me(msg) do 
    message = 
      with nil <- Repo.get_by(Rewards, user: msg.author.id),
           changeset <- Rewards.changeset(%Rewards{}, %{user: msg.author.id}),
           {:ok, _} <- Repo.insert(changeset) do 
        ":white_check_mark:"
      else
        {:error, _} -> ":x:"
        _ -> "You're already registered"
      end
    Api.create_message(msg.channel_id, message)
  end
```

You can reduce some of the one-time variables in `thanks` like this:

```
  def thanks(msg) do
    Enum.map msg.mentions, fn user ->
      repo_user = Repo.get_by(Rewards, user: user.id)

      repo_user
      |> Ecto.Changeset.change(quantity: repo_user.points + 1)
      |> Repo.update!
      Api.create_message(msg.channel_id, "#{msg.author.username} gave a :cookie: to #{user.username}")
    end
  end
```

Finally, it appears that you don't care about the type of error on the Repo.insert. Keep in mind that the changeset returned with `{:error, changeset}` contains the validation errors.

NOTE:

I see 4 common style / issues with programmers learning Elixir.

1. **error** Calling a side affect free function without using the return value. Data in Elixir is immutable, so you need need to either capture the results of a function, call it as the last statement so it returned to the caller, or create a side effect in the function (send an event, write to database, file, etc)
2. **warning** Use a variable outside the scope of the block it was set in. In other words, don't set a variable inside an if, case, or cond, then use it later
3. **style** Use lots of single use variables. This is typically a sign that the pipe `|>` operator may clean up the code.
4. **style** Use logs of conditional statements where multi-clause function heads with pattern matching and guards may make the code cleaner, with less nesting

Comment: Hello Steve, thank you very much, I have some questions regarding this solution that I hope you can clear out. 1st. Do I have to use a Changeset even if I don't want a validation? Because when I insert a value the user doesn't input any information, I'm getting it from a struct attached to the user automatically, the only thing the user does is call the command. 2nd. I've read about `with` before but honestly I didn't quite understand it so I didn't know it could be used in this case, does it work like a nest `case` statement or something else? I will look further into it and...

Comment: ... 3rd. I don't actually care (in this case) for the validation errors on `Repo.insert`, because how I said, I'm not validating any data or I may be wrong? So, should I explicitly check the changeset returned with `{:error, changeset}` when I'm validating the data? Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: No, you don't need to pass Repo.insert a changeset. Your code will work fine. If you don't care about validation errors then you don't need to check. If you do care about validation errors, then `changeset.errors` will give you the list. Finally, when I first started using the with operator, I found it a little confusing and hard to remember. However, after using it for a while, its very easy to use and a very nice tool to reduce nesting and handling errors in the middle of a pipeline.